# How to display author post count for multiple custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, count

On my theme `author.php` page I have a number of posts displayed but it only count posts of the type 'post', I need it to count multiple post types.

I think they are trying to make this core but no updates for a while, see the ticket [#32243](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32243).

I'm not a coder so I don't really know how to make it, can someone help me?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code from your theme? What multiple post types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ticket was fixed and closed in version 4.3.

Make sure you got the latest version ( currently 4.4.2 )

If we check out the inline documentation for the `count_user_posts()` we find this part:

```
* @since 4.3.0 Added `$public_only` argument. Added the ability to pass an array
*              of post types to `$post_type`.
```

Note the default post type for that function is `post`.

So you will most likely have to add the post types you want, here's an example:

```
echo count_user_posts( 
    $userid = 1, 
    $post_type = [ 'post', 'page' ], 
    $public_only = false 
);
```

to get the count for the user with *user id* as 1 and post types *post* and *page*.

Comment: Thanks this did it! i just couldn't find a codex that explain the usage like you did. it maybe there isn't one yet

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you @lauraLalas